# Need Suggestion while handle huge pipe data

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm practicing C code with pipe system call, it works well with small chunks of data. but as the data goes beyond the pipe capacity, dead lock occurs.

My test system is Debian Sid, but i believe it share the common ground with other Linux distributions. This piece of code works well while the input file '/tmp/a.out' is small enough to fit within the pipe, but blocked as the file is up to 1M.

```
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHUNK 2048
int main() {
    int fd=open("/tmp/a.out",O_RDONLY);
    int pin[2];
    int pout[2];

    int nread;
    char buff[CHUNK];

    pipe(pin);
    pipe(pout);
    int rc;
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(pin[1]);
        dup2(pin[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pout[0]);
        dup2(pout[1],STDOUT_FILENO);

        execlp("cat","cat",(char *)0);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        close(pin[0]);
        close(pout[1]);

/* I think dead lock occurs here, but i can't figure out a way to avoid it */ 
        while ( (nread=read(fd,buff,CHUNK)) > 0) write(pin[1],buff,nread);
        close(pin[1]);
        while ( (nread=read(pout[0],buff,CHUNK)) >0) write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,nread);



        waitpid(pid,&rc,0);
        exit(rc);

    } else {
        perror("fork");
        exit(errno);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?   I know Python's subprocess class have something like subprocess.communicate() to avoid this kind of dead lock, but i don't know how to deal with it in C.

Many thanks.

Comment: The typical idiom is: `close(pin[1]); dup2(pin[0], STDIN_FILENO); close(pin[0])`.  You are leaving `pin[0]` and `pout[1]` open in the child.  Do a count: when you call execlp you should only have 3 open file descriptors.  The process started with 3.  You called pipe twice, bringing the total up to 7.  You should therefore call `close` 4 times before you call `exec`.  (You can think of the implicit close that occurs from dup2 as one, but if you do you need to increment the total).  Basically, for each call to `pipe`, you should call `close` twice.

Comment: You current code blocks when you reach about 128 KiB of data.  You've just demonstrated why you don't normally create loops with sets of pipes.  You can achieve concurrency by having a third process read the output from `cat`, or by having multiple threads with one handling the writing to `cat` and the other reading from `cat`.  I believe you could also use `select()` or `poll()` (or, on Linux, `epoll()`) on the pipe descriptors.  Or you can do what is suggested in [Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412080/maxim-egorushkin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264891/15168).

Comment: Ahh..., concurrency, that's a good suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first process pipes into `cat` and `cat` pipes back into the first process. Hence, for `cat` to not block on piping back, the first process must also drain that pipe. E.g.:

```
fcntl(pout[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(pout[0], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
while((nread=read(fd, buff, CHUNK)) > 0) {
    write(pin[1], buff, nread); // TODO: check errors and partial writes here.
    while((nread=read(pout[0],buff,CHUNK)) > 0) // pout[0] must be set into non-blocking mode.
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, nread);
}
```

A more robust way is to set both `pin[1]` and `pout[0]` into non-blocking mode, use `select` to determine whether `pin[1]` is ready for write and `pout[0]` for read and then do write/read correspondingly and handle partial reads and writes.

Comment: So stupid, should have considered non-blocking IO. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your suggestions at least I have 2 ways to solve this problem 
1. Setting 'NON-BLOCK' mode by 'fcntl' or 'select/poll/epoll'

2. Use concurrency such as 'pthread' for stdin pipe 
   piece of code attached.

```
        struct data {
             int from_fd;
             int to_fd;
        };
```

and code for pipes should look like

```
        pthread_t t;
        struct data d;
        d.from_fd=fd;
        d.to_fd=pin[1];
        pthread_create(&t,NULL,&fd_to_pipe,(void*) &d);

        while ( (nread=read(pout[0],buff,CHUNK)) >0) write(STDOUT_FILENO,buff,nread);

        waitpid(pid,&rc,0);
        pthread_join(t,NULL);
```

Thank you !